# file reading event handler weirdness with javascript/html5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to install an event handler in JavaScript to do some work on loading a file (I'm testing using Chrome). This is the Javascript I'm using:

```
// file reader...

function handleFileSelect(evt) 
{
    alert('event changed called!');
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    f = files[0];
    reader.readAsText(f);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt)
    {
        // alert(evt.target.result);
        alert('moo!');
    }
}

alert('adding event listener');
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

The weird thing is that the alerts aren't firing, so I'm assuming that I've installed them incorrectly. I'm not sure what the mistake is though. Any ideas?

EDIT: Sorry, I should mention that it's the handleFileSelect(...) event handler that isn't firing.

Thank you for your time...

Comment: **Always** check the browser developer tools for errors when things aren't working as you expect.

Comment: You are calling `reader.readAsText()` before defining the `reader` variable.

Comment: Thank you Pointy, I did not realise Chrome had a dev tools option (I've lived too long in Visual Studio-ville). The issue was that the callback was being installed before the page had loaded. Setting the 'onload' callback in the body of the page fixed my issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You call `reader.readAsText(f);` before you assign `reader` to a value, so you get an error trying to call `readAsText` from an undefined value.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(f);
```

Comment: Thanks for that catch. However, the handleFileSelect(...) still isn't being called (the alert at the top of that function never gets fired).